# How to iterate over a JSON response and store values in Pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics

I make a request to Google Analytics API v4 using this code:

```py
responses = []

for k, v in data_test.items():

    sample_request = {
        'viewId': v['view_id'],
        'dateRanges': {
            'startDate': v['start_date'],
            'endDate': v['end_date']
        },
        'metrics': v['metrics'],
        'dimensions': v['dimensions']
    }

    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': sample_request
        }).execute()

    n_response=print_response_new(response)
    #dict_responses.update(response)


    responses.append(n_response)
    #responses.append(response)
```

It iterates over a nested dict with parameters, like this:

```
data_test = {

    'view_id_01' : {'view_id': '01', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-02',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:userType'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]}

'view_id_02' : {'view_id': '02', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-02',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]},

'view_id_03' : {'view_id': '03', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-02',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]}
}
```

I have a JSON response and need to convert it in a Pandas DF.

Example of a response:

```
{'reports': [{'columnHeader': {'dimensions': ['ga:userAgeBracket',
                                              'ga:userGender'],
                               'metricHeader': {'metricHeaderEntries': [{'name': 'ga:sessions',
                                                                         'type': 'INTEGER'}]}},
              'data': {'maximums': [{'values': ['3682']}],
                       'minimums': [{'values': ['411']}],
                       'rowCount': 12,
                       'rows': [{'dimensions': ['18-24', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['654']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['18-24', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['432']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['25-34', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['3682']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['25-34', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['2683']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['35-44', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['2126']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['35-44', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['2141']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['45-54', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['1183']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['45-54', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['1042']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['55-64', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['1111']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['55-64', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['730']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['65+', 'female'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['448']}]},
                                {'dimensions': ['65+', 'male'],
                                 'metrics': [{'values': ['411']}]}],
                       'totals': [{'values': ['16643']}]}}]}
```

I could convert it in an ordinary DF, here the code:

```
def print_response_new_test(response):

    list = []

    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])


        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            dict[header] = dimension


        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

        list.append(dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    df['start_date'] = sample_request.get('start_date')
    df['end_date'] = sample_request.get('end_date')
    df['view_id'] = sample_request.get('view_id')
    return df
```

It results in such DF:

```
browser   country  sessions users start_date  end_date    view_id

chrome    china    100      90    2019-01-01  2019-01-02  01
mozilla   germany  200      190   2019-01-01  2019-01-02  02
safari    france   300      290   2019-01-01  2019-01-02  03
```

But I need to like change the DF that it should look like that:

```
start_date  end_date    view_id element_1 element_2 metrics  m_value

2019-01-01  2019-01-02  01      chrome    china     sessions 100
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  01      chrome    china     users    90
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  02      mozilla   germany   sessions 200
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  02      mozilla   germany   users    190
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  03      safari    france    sessions 300
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  03      safari    france    users    290
```

And the problem is that the columns are not fixed, values and the number of columns can differ.

I'm not even sure with what should I start, change the print_response_new_test function or change the resulted df

Comment: Your desired output contains data that is not in the `JSON` response, for example, `element_1` and `element_2` are not in the response.

Comment: Yeah, true, this df table will be sent to a database, and there columns are named like this. I mean element_1, element_2 etc.

Comment: Did you post the right JSON response? I don't see values like China or Gernany anywhere in the JSON